# Safari implementing display:none differently to other browsers

Tags: css, browser, safari, hover, hidden

**Problem:** 
I have a CSS bug which is occurring solely in Safari and not any other browser (back to IE8). It is not being caused by an experimental/unsupported feature and so feature sniffing is not a solution. Essentially it seems to be implementing `display:hidden` & `display:table` incorrectly.

I considered loading a separate stylesheet for Safari but the unreliability of browser sniffing is not something I want to depend on.

**Details:**
I have a text box that is being applied `display:hidden` on hover of another element. The text box is no longer being rendered but seems to be interacting with other elements on the page, as the element that is being displayed instead is forced down the page. I know this should be an impossibility but cannot figure out why the remaining elements are being affected.

**JSBin**

This [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/giqatetosa/1/edit?output) demonstrates the page working perfectly as intended in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE tested back to IE8, and some mobile browsers. However when opened in Safari (and the page is wide enough to fit both textarea elements on the same line) the elements reshuffle when the hover effects are applied.

Can anyone please spot what the issue is here or what can be changed to make it browser consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container `.my-box` is set to `display: inline-block`. The default value for vertical align in CSS is `baseline`. Safari somehow seems to align the contained elements (with `display: table` and `display: inline-block`) in `.my-box` different from other browsers. You can force Safari (and all other browsers) to align all elements to the top, using this CSS:

```
.my-box {
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsbin.com/hucitukeyi/1/edit?output)

Comment: With some other minor edits this has allowed me to finally fix the issue. Thanks!